# Error: repository epel, mysql, rhela and webtatic is listed more than once in the configuration

Tags: php, repository, upgrade, rhel

I currently have php53 installed redhat version 6.8

```
[rh@StorServIN ~]$ php -v
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2015 04:52:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

but when I want to upgrade php 5.3 to php 7.2 in redhat 6.8, following error comes out:

```
[rh@StorServIN etc]$ sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Repository epel-debuginfo is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository epel-source is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository mysql57-community is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository rhel-source is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository webtatic is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository webtatic-debuginfo is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository webtatic-source is listed more than once in the configuration
epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm                                                                                           |  14 kB     00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-Pdnwyw/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm: epel-release-6-8.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-Pdnwyw/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I'm new in RHEL. How can I solve this?